# Template option is missing

Tags: wordpress, templates

I am facing a problem over and again. The problem is template option missing at the WordPress Dashboard. How can I make visible template option at WordPress dashboard?

[image]

I have also created a `templete.php` file in my root folder - `wp-content\themes\twentyseventeen`,  but it's not working.

I am using version 4.9 of WordPress.

Comment: its showing .......Warning: file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\gohigh/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/custompage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\gohigh\wp-includes\class-wp-theme.php on line 1042

Comment: Go through this, https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Comment: Can you show the headers of your template?

Comment: right now same problem happening again...its not showing templete option in page attribue...though I changed my theme

Comment: Show the header code in your template..or just past the entire template code here. Need more info to diagnose the issue man..

Answer (score 2):

Check if your index.php file is in place.

If it's not there, wordpress treats the template as corrupt and it doesn't display the template selection.

Also,
I solved this problem solved by adding the typical following code:

```
/*
Template Name: Custom
*/
```

Don't add any spaces after  Name:

It'll work if you use template name: as well.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the template file name you have saved in the root directory of your theme **prefixed "template"**.

Example: save the file as `template-xxxxx.php`.